# nothing returned from win32::gui::LoadImage

Tags: win32gui, strawberry-perl

I am using Strawberry Perl (v5.16.3) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread and win32::GUI on a Microsoft Windows 7 system. I am using Eclipse/EPIC to write and test the code.

I am trying to display a picture / bitmap / Icon / Cursor. Have tried all 3, results the same nothing is returned from win32::gui::LoadImage.

I have added some print lines to gui.PM for debugging and I have a test script to test for this gui function.  Since the code for win32::gui::LoadImage subroutine is not in the GUI.PM module, is it being included from the C library or windows?  Does there need to be changes to the code calling win32::gui::LoadImage?

In advance thanks for the help
Bob

```
## print lines added to gui.PM for debugging ##########
## (Lines are Suffixed with comment #Bob) #############

package Win32::GUI::Bitmap;
@ISA = qw(Win32::GUI);
end;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {};

my $inputa =shift @_; #Bob

print "Len=" . length($inputa)."\n"; #Bob

#   my $handle = Win32::GUI::LoadImage(@_); #Bob commented out the origional
    my $handle = Win32::GUI::LoadImage($inputa, 0, 0, 0, 0); #Bob

print "Gui.PM(Win32::GUI::_new) self='$self' input='@_' inputa='$inputa' \n ";# Bob
print "Gui.PM handle=".$handle."  ".$self."\n";  #Bob
# TODO: this gives us a bitmap object, even if we ask for a cursor!


#### test script ####################################################
    use Win32::GUI();
our $Window = Win32::GUI::Window->new(
    -name => "Window",
    -top => 120,
    -left => 120,
    -height => 300,
    -width => 300
    );

our $Icon="";
    $Icon = Win32::GUI::Bitmap->new("eclipse16.gif") ;#or die $^E; 
print "Test Icon=".$Icon."\n";  # See if Bitmap return anything

our $Button = $Window -> AddButton(
    -name => "Icon",
    -text => "Icon",
    -top => 50,
    -left => 50,
    -height => 100,
    -width => 100,
    -picture => $Icon,
    -icon => $Icon,
    -bitmap => $Icon,  # add this line here, try if works
    );

#    $Window->$Button-> $Bitmap ;

$Window->SetIcon($Icon);

    $Window->Show();
    Win32::GUI::Dialog();

    sub Window_Terminate {
    return -1;
    }
```